# Short story (1960s?) - alien changes shape to appeal to male human. Thrown out of car, then re-assembles necklace from fender

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Shape-changing alien falls in love with human man.  Its chest, in desperation, turns into appendages to reach out, and when thrown out of a convertible, "she" hangs on to auto and uses fender to re-assemble necklace. Old short-story.

Comment: I have read this, and was half convinced it was in Isaac Asimov's Great Stories collection. Unfortunately neither pdfgrepping for "fender" or "chrome" turned out anything. The human was a criminal, wasn't he?

Answer (score 6):

[The Night He Cried](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57305) by Fritz Leiber.

Your memory of the story is slightly off. The human is a gangster called Slickie Millane and the alien is an envoy from Galaxy Centre sent to try and reform him.

The scene you're thinking off with the chest appendages is at the end of the story when the alien has had a bit too much to drink:

> Then I realized that in my excitement, instead of using my upper dorsal tentacles, I’d used the upper ventral ones I kept transmuted into my beautiful milk glands. I do suppose they looked rather strange to Slickie as they came out of the bosom of my off-the-shoulders evening dress and drew him to me.
> Frightening sounds came out of him. I let him go and tried to resume my gorgeous shape, but now I was really confused (that last half liter!) and lost control of my transmutations. When I found myself turning my topmost tentacle into a milk gland I gave up completely and—except for a lung and vocal cords—resumed my normal shape. It was quite a relief. After all, I had done what Galaxy Center had intended I should. From now on, the mere sight of a brassiere in a show window would be enough to give Slickie the shakes.
> Still, I was bothered about the guy. As I say, he’d touched me.
> I caressed him tenderly with my tentacles. Over and over again I explained that I was just a heptapus and that Galaxy Center had selected me for the job simply because my seven tentacles would transmute nicely into the seven extremities of the human female.
> Over and over again I told him how I loved him.
> It didn’t seem to help. Slickie Millane continued to weep hysterically.